# I have a problem with image upload using Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, upload

I have a problem with image upload. But I have already used many time same mechanism but right now the problem.
anyone can help me to find out the solution?

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: You need to include all errors and code as text in the question, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Symphony source returns file size of 0 if the file size is larger than php.ini's upload_max_filesize.

So check your upload_max_filesize in the php.ini file. The upload_max_filesize may be smaller than the file you're attempting to upload.

Comment: No this one is not problem. i have already upload many image from another controller using same mechanism. Also i just try to upload a 3kb file. Please check blow link it's from laravel git repository https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30064

Answer (score 0):

The error could be caused by many reasons like php config, etc.
I think the code needs a little bit of refactoring, try to make use of Laravel's [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem) and [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators). Take a look at [Dependency injections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) also.

If you are using Laravel 6 or 7
A way to implement file upload would be:

In your view:

```
/* 
 * make sure that the form has the attribute:
 * enctype="multipart/form-data"
 * or else no file will be passed
 * */
<form action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">....
```

In your Controlller's `updateSetting` method:

```
public function updateSetting(Request $request, Setting $settings)
{
    // do your validations and others

    $settings->update($request->all());
    // else: $settings->create($request->all());

    // * you could use eloquent's updateOrCreate() method, look for it in the documentation        

    // your redirect code...
}
```

And in your Setting model, add a mutator that handles setting of the admin logo as well as uploading the file and deleting the old one. (You could also create a helper for the upload logic)

```
public function setAdminLogoAttribute($value)
{
    // Add your delete old admin logo logic

    if (is_file($value)) {
        $fileName = time() . "_" . $value->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $value->move(
            public_path('uploads'),
            $fileName
        ); // or create a handleImage() helper

        $this->attributes['admin_logo'] = $fileName;
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work there probably an issue with the configuration, or maybe not, you could try to give us more information of how specifically the error occured

Comment: I have already solved this issue by only changed the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this issue I just changed the name.

```
        $ext= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name = time()."." . $ext;
```